# Web site on IIS needed login and password to access

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, iis-6, asp.net, server-settings

I am using some web hosting provider (Windows, IIS, ASP.NET). My site worked good. One day I got an error "You are not authorized to view this page. HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to an ACL set on the requested resource." when I tried just access my site. So I had to input login and password to access my home page.

Has anyone ever got so error? I am appreciated to get any help.

Configuration:
Windows 2003 Server Enterprise
IIS 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My domain was still pointing to the old server. 
Hence I was not able to access the website. 
It has pointed to the new server and now it is working!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue with your guest user. You could have a look at this article, it may be able to help.

http://portal.hostingcontroller.com/KB/a3/site-is-asking-login-password-0r-throwing-you-are-not.aspx